# Efficiently getting previous value with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

As I am working with a rather large data set, I am looking for a more efficient way of getting previous values based on a date sequence. I am currently using a SELECT TOP 1 sub query for each value, but this takes a lot of time each time i run the query

Sample Data:

```
TDate       Object    Price     Volume
18.05.2017  ObjectA     105      10
18.05.2017  ObjectB     110      10
18.05.2017  ObjectC     120      10
19.05.2017  ObjectA     100      12
19.05.2017  ObjectB     75       10
19.05.2017  ObjectD     33       10
22.05.2017  ObjectA     105      15
22.05.2017  ObjectB     80       10
22.05.2017  ObjectD     55       10
```

My Code:

```
SELECT  TDate AS TodaysDate, Object, Price AS TodaysPrice, Volume AS   TodaysVolume,
( SELECT TOP 1 TDate
                              FROM Table1 AS P2
                              WHERE P2.Object = Table1.Object
                                AND P2.TDate < Table1.TDate
                              ORDER BY P2.TDate DESC ) As prevDate,
( SELECT TOP 1 Price
                              FROM Table1 AS P2
                              WHERE P2.Object = Table1.Object
                                AND P2.TDate < Table1.TDate
                              ORDER BY P2.TDate DESC ) As prevPrice,
( SELECT TOP 1 Volume
                              FROM Table1 AS P2
                              WHERE P2.Object = Table1.Object
                                AND P2.TDate < Table1.TDate
                              ORDER BY P2.TDate DESC ) As PrevVolume
FROM Table1
```

Output:

```
TodaysDate  Object  TodaysPrice TodaysVolume    prevDate    prevPrice   PrevVolume
18.05.2017  ObjectA     105     10          
18.05.2017  ObjectB     110     10          
18.05.2017  ObjectC     120     10          
19.05.2017  ObjectA     100     12              18.05.2017      105     10
19.05.2017  ObjectB     75      10              18.05.2017      110     10
19.05.2017  ObjectD     33      10          
22.05.2017  ObjectA     105     15              19.05.2017      100     12
22.05.2017  ObjectB     80      10              19.05.2017      75      10
22.05.2017  ObjectD     55      10              19.05.2017      33      10
```

The output is correct, but I would greatly appreciate input on two things;

1) Is there any way to more efficently compute the previous date and values? (I am using Microsoft Access 2010)

2) How can I incorporate the price difference between TodaysPrice and PrevPrice directly in the SQL-code?

Thank you in advance for any advice and input!

Comment: Is PrevDate ALWAYS EXACTLY one month prior to TodaysDate?

Comment: No - there is no pattern in the dates unfortunately. PrevDate is the previous date the object is listed in the Table (i.e. if its over a weekend, the previous day will be last Friday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sub-query

```
SELECT   TodaysDate, TodaysObject, TodaysPrice, TodaysVolume, Today.PrevDate,
    prev.Price  as PrevPrice, prev.Volume as PrevVolume
FROM (
    SELECT  TDate AS TodaysDate, Object as TodaysObject, Price AS TodaysPrice, Volume AS   TodaysVolume,
        Table1.Object, ( SELECT MAX(P2.TDate)
                              FROM Table1 AS P2
                              WHERE P2.Object = Table1.Object
                                AND P2.TDate < Table1.TDate ) As PrevDate
    FROM Table1) Today
    LEFT JOIN Table1 as Prev ON Today.TodaysObject= Prev.Object AND Today.PrevDate = Prev.TDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! The code you provided doesn't work as-is, but I will try to find out why

Comment: Add an alias to subquery's Object Field  e.g. `SELECT TDate AS TodaysDate, Object AS TodayObject, Price AS TodaysPrice, ...`